# google cloud platform forward ports 80,443 to port 8501 (streamlit) for single VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, streamlit, portforwarding

I am setting up a Streamlit server on Google Cloud Platform.  I have my server working correctly on a single VM instance at myip:8501.  But I am stuck on how to forward traffic from myip:80 and myip:443 to 8501. There is a way to do this for instance groups using load balancers, but I only have  one instance and don't need more.  Can anyone provide insight on how to do this using gcloud?

Comment: You cannot forward both http and https to the same port without performing SSL offloading.

Answer (score 0):

There are a boatload of options you have, but assuming your goal is just getting the traffic to arrive and nothing more fancy, these are the ones I'd contemplate:

1. Run a reverse proxy like nginx or httpd that directs the traffic on 80 to 8051
2. Wrap your machine in an (unmanaged) instance group and put an HTTP load balancer in front of it that remaps the ports

For 443/https you just terminate the ssl at the lb or reverse proxy and send the http traffic to streamlit.

Since you mention streamlit I can already tell you from experience that you will need to take precautions so that the websocket traffic is handled correctly. See this entry for nginx, but note that the path has changed from `/stream` to something else in recent versions of streamlit: https://github.com/Taxuspt/heroku_streamlit_nginx/blob/master/config/nginx.conf.erb#L54

With an external http load balancer you will most likely need to increase the timeout for the streamlit websocket to work well, see here: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#websocket_support